# what's the name of this org. compound. RR'-C=NNH2

Tags: nomenclature

What's the name of this compound? It's a semi-product of Wolff-Kishner reduction.

[image: img]

The complete reaction is:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (now deleted) [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65452/7951) by [NotCorey](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/21296/notcorey) has already explained that the compound that is shown in the picture is a hydrazone that is derived from acetone (propan-2-one).

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) for a hydrazone is generated substitutively as ‘ylidene’ derivatives of hydrazine rather than by functional class nomenclature as in previous recommendations.

> **P-68.3.1.2.2** Hydrazones
>
> Compounds having the general structure $\ce{RCH=N-NH2}$ or $\ce{RR'C=N-NH2}$ are called ‘hydrazones’ and are named in two ways:
>
> (1) substitutively as derivatives of the parent hydride ‘hydrazine’, $\ce{H2N-NH2}$;
>
> (2) by functional class nomenclature using the class name ‘hydrazone’.
>
> Method (1) generates preferred IUPAC names.

Therefore, the PIN for the compound that is given in the question is **(propan-2-ylidene)hydrazine.**

[image: (propan-2-ylidene)hydrazine]